# Securing a Javascript / PayPal checkout form

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, paypal

I am building a PayPal checkout form with KnockoutJS on the frontend and the PayPal-PHP-SDK on the backend.

The checkout sends shopping cart data in json via AJAX. There is no sensitive user data sent, only itemsID, item options and the item amounts.
PHP on the server has all the matching prices, sanitizes the received json and sums up the totals, checks in with the PayPal API and returns an approval url. User gets redirected to that URL.

The AJAX call on the checkout:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "process.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: jsonData,
            success: function(data){
              location = data;
        },
        error:function(){
            $("#status").html('There is error while submit');
        }
});
```

Is this secure enough? What are other common best practices when dealing with ajax calls and PHP?

Comment: AJAX call is not different from any other http request. Treat them equally.

Comment: All user submitted input has the same degree of trustworthyness no matter what HTTP request method you use. You need to make sure that your PHP is sound to validate and sanitise the data. You said that you deal with this already so there's not much more you can do with a front end technology.

Answer (score 1):

If no explicit personal data is being sent then there should be no issue.But keep in mind that it is always best to send a HTTPS/SSL request when working with payments and personal data for security purposes.

But Ajax post calls are basically the same as a form submit, so if you think the normal form submit is not secure enough, then the ajax call will be no different.